# how to limit the locale of amazon mturk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I have an external page HIT based on the AWS command-line tools for mturk.

I want to limit the HIT so that only people from a certain country can view/accept the HIT (say, India, etc.)

How can I do that using the command-line tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a locale qualification to your `hit.properties` file:

For example, for just India:

```
qualification.1:00000000000000000071
qualification.locale.1:IN
qualification.comparator.1:EqualTo
```